# How do I get the current Editor of an Listitem while ItemUpdating?

Tags: event-receivers, splistitem, updatelistitems

How can I get the current Editor of an list Item in SharePoint 2010 during `ItemUpdating`?

Problem is `properties.AfterProperties["Editor"].ToString()` throws and Exception cause it's null. This `properties.ListItem["Editor"].ToString()` is useless cause I get the Editor which made changes the last time.

Any guess how I can achieve this during the Updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use properties.UserLoginName to get the current use. Note if you running your code in RunWithElevatedPreveliges, you need to write above statement before that.

Comment: I used this in my case properties.UserDisplayName